# lightest non-modal dialog with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, dialog

Here is a demo:

http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/

But it's too huge for me.

There are 2 thousand lines included in all.

I'd like to have one in a single file with less than 1 thousand lines.

Comment: How small does it need to be to qualify?

Comment: too huge in what way? is the dialog physically too large for your content? is the required plugin script too large for you to include on your page?

Comment: easiest to roll your own however a feature list would help. What do you want the dialog to do? jQuery ui has to cater for many requirements.

Comment: "to cater for many requirements." - Including cross-browser compatibility.

Comment: well showing a layered div is not rocket science x-browser...

Answer (score 10):

If you have an aversion to the complexity implied by a high line-count, you need to get over this or you'll end up doing [voodoo](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11782951/154066), reimplementing from scratch for lack of trust, and choosing slightly-less-complex-looking but ultimately inferior libraries.

I say this because you ask for fewer lines of code, which is a good metric for complexity and maintainability, but a poor metric for important things like good design and good docs. Even size is seldom an issue, if you use minified code.

Take a deep breath and just include the file :)

Answer (score 4):

You can strip JQueryUI to its bare essentials by unchecking all of the things you don't need from the download when you get it at http://jqueryui.com/download.

I would imagine that you can get it below 1000 lines if you do this.

Comment: Just over 1100 (non-minified) lines and 32K with just core and dialog.

Comment: how to implement this:
click on a link,then pop up the dialog where click happens.

Comment: is there a bare bones version I can get from bower with just the popup

Answer (score 0):

@Shore:
To implement this,

HTML code:

```
<a id="clickme">Open Dialog</a>

<div id="dialog" style="display:none;">Hello this is a dialog</div>
```

JS code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // Default settings for dialog
    $("#dialog").dialog({
        bgiframe: true,
        height: 300,
        width: 350,
        autoOpen: false,
        modal: true,
        overlay: { 
            opacity: 0.7,
            background: "black"
        }
    });
   $('#clickme').click(function(){
      $("#dialog").dialog('open');
   }); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I like jqmodal. (it's not necessarily modal!)
It's about 3k.

[jqmodal link](http://dev.iceburg.net/jquery/jqModal/)

Init

```
$('#dialog').jqm();
```

Show

```
$('#dialog').jqmShow();
```

Comment: That looks like it's modal

Answer (score 0):

I was asking myself the same question. Where can I find a lightweight overlay plugin without including jQuery UI?
After I aproximately spend an hour searching the web I decided to implement it on my own.

**So after three years the answer is:**
You might try [jquery.mloverlay](http://plugins.jquery.com/mloverlay/) a simple, lightweight jQuery plugin for showing modal less overlays.