# Modeless Javascript Prompt

Tags: javascript, prompt

How can I create a javascript prompt that floats in a fixed position on a page?

More specifically I am trying to create a floating prompt or dialog box that asks for a user ID and creates a cookie with that id number.  It can't be accomplished with a simple javascript prompt because the user needs to be answer the prompt at will and still be able to access the parent window (ie modeless).  Also, it must be accomplished by simply including a script (no html or divs) because it will be given to several clients and we want to keep it as simple for them as possible to implement.

This would require asynchronous javascript, correct?  How would I go about creating this?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1291336/lightest-non-modal-dialog-with-jquery

Comment: And no, creating a cookie does not require Ajax, if that's what you mean with "asynchronous javascript". The code will only run (synchronously) when the user types enter, presses the submit button, or whatever.

Comment: Thanks for feedback Zecc, I wish it was a duplicate because I would have found my answer days ago...
I am asking for asychronous javascript, therefore the page load or any actions in the page can continue uninterupted by the prompt.  I included the example of the cookie just as an example, I wasn't asking how to create a cookie.

Comment: A better example might would be creating something similar to a floating chat window (but only client-side and not requiring server interaction) that floats over a page while the page can still be accessed by the user.