# What is shotgun/voodoo programming?

Tags: terminology

I saw the term in [in this question](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/2992/in-an-exit-interview-how-do-i-tell-my-manager-about-my-replacements-lack-of).  I think I have an idea, but not sure if this a localized term or if wide spread meaning for the term.

Shotgun would implie that he might be (over) using a tool or technique much bulkier or clunkier than a simpler, more elegant solution can be found.  And voodoo?

Comment: http://catb.org/jargon/html/V/voodoo-programming.html

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shotgun_surgery

Comment: Also [shotgun debugging](http://catb.org/jargon/html/S/shotgun-debugging.html)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

*Shotgun* implies blindly scattering a million little bits of junk all over a problem, like the pellets in a shotgun shell; hopefully one little bit hits the mark. It's trying stuff until something works, rather then understanding what's going on.

*Voodoo* implies doing something because of magical beliefs, or more specifically, doing something for an unknown reason, especially something overly complicated: "I've always done it this way, I don't know why it works."

Neither characterization is flattering: they imply ignorance and incompetence.

Comment: I always called Shotgun programming "Hack and Slash" because you're just kind of taking wild swings at the problem. That and the nice little double entendre of "hack".

Comment: Great answer, but I'd just like to add that most programmers, when picking up a new language, have little choice but to rely on shotgun and voodoo programming until they get used to the language; they don't grok the language, even though they may theoretically understand its structure. Once they are accustomed to the language, they can lose the bad programming habits. In that sense, I prefer to add to those definitions the words "when the programmer should know better".

Comment: @Palladium Very nice introspective