# Why is my subprocess call failing?

Tags: python, subprocess, youtube-dl

I am trying to play with the subprocess library.

`$youtube-dl http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=co5gy_2uOEY` on the terminal works as expected but the following code snippet run in the IDLE doesn't seem to do anything.

```
> os.chdir('/home/andrew')
> line = 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=co5gy_2uOEY'
> yt_dl = subprocess.call(['youtube-dl',line])
1
```

Alternatively, I also tried:

```
> yt_dl = subprocess.Popen(['youtube-dl',line])
```

but that returned `1` and didn't do anything either. What's going on here?

EDIT:

Wrapping line with double quotes made it work, but now this subprocess hangs. I tried to make the following change, and it didn't work yet again:

```
yt_dl = ["youtube-dl","http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=co5gy_2uOEY"]
x = subprocess.Popen(yt_dl, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
stdout, stderr = x.communicate()
```

Comment: should `line` be a string?

Comment: This code works for me.

Comment: have you tried to add shell=True?

Comment: @KatFarrell shotgun programming?

Comment: @KatFarrell http://stackoverflow.com/q/11782951/113586

Comment: @wRAR apologies - you were right (just checked the implementation of subprocess).

Comment: @isedev you needed to check `execve(3)` instead.

Comment: Why are you using `PIPE` for `stdout` and `stdin`? Do you actually need the output? (And why not `stderr=PIPE` or `stderr=STDIN`, because it looks like you need the err as much as the output.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It hangs because it works. You can check the terminal from which you run `idle` for the `youtube-dl` output.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you don't get an error about `http` not being defined, but you should use:

```
line = "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=co5gy_2uOEY"
```

To pass a string to `subprocess.call`

Comment: Check out the edit? That worked, but it hanged, and calling Popen didn't work.

Answer (score -2):

have you tried to add shell=True? (Although this is generally discouraged.)

> yt_dl = subprocess.Popen(['youtube-dl',line] shell=True)

Comment: If you can trust your own system then it should be fine. I did point out that this is discouraged..

Comment: It's not about danger, it's about doing random things in the hope that they might help.

Comment: At the Jargon file says in its definition of ["shotgun debugging"](http://catb.org/jargon/html/S/shotgun-debugging.html): "the making of relatively undirected changes to software in the hope that a bug will be perturbed out of existence. This almost never works, and usually introduces more bugs." Or, worse, it _does_ work one time early in your career, and you become a cargo-cult programmer and never learn how to be useful.