# Perl: Remove record with special character from an array

Tags: perl

I want to find and remove record from an array. I am using option1 but it's not working. Value in array1 value is like

```
abc::record1 
def:record2
ghf::record3 
poi::record4
```

and value which need to be compared is like record1,record2,record3 which is in variable item.

Option 1 :

```
my @found = grep( /^$item$/, @array1 );

if (@found){
      @array = eval { grep(!/$item/, @array1); };
      @array1 = @array;

     }
```

Shall I try with option 2 , will this look for exact match or any value in string/line?

Option2

```
@array = grep { $_ ne $item } @array1;
@array1 = @array;
```

Thanks

Comment: Don't understand what you are asking for. What is in $item? Can you show wanted output?

Comment: This looks like shotgun "school of thought" http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11782951/what-is-shotgun-voodoo-programming

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as I understand your question I would suggest Option 3:

```
foreach (@array1){
   if ($item == $_) { < -  This is the current element of the array
      Do What you want
   }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply unse splice to remove an array element, the syntax is

splice @array, $first_index [, $number_of_replaced_element] [, @values]

- @array is the array you want modify.
- $number_of_replaced_element: the number of element you want to modify or delete
- @values: values to insert

e.g:

```
my @array = (1,2,3,4,5,6);
# delete the third element
splice @array, 2, 1;
# replace the third element by 1
splice @array, 2, 1, 1;
# delete each element after thz second
splice @array, 2;
```