# Gradle Plugin Error - Plugin is too old, please update to a more recent version, or set ANDROID_DAILY_OVERRIDE environment variable to

Tags: android-studio, gradle, gradle-plugin

I was working on my app. Suddenly, this error shows up. I tried updating everything, but still can't get rid of this error. Please help.

Error:

> Error:(1, 0) Plugin is too old, please update to a more recent
>   version, or set ANDROID_DAILY_OVERRIDE environment variable to
>   "ecd0a1cd36b714e2e8c64a08bff878b8e7f54e0a"

build.gradle:

[image]

classpath:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

These are all the android plugin version available that are newer than `2.0.0-alpha5`

```
2.0.0-beta5
2.0.0-beta4
2.0.0-beta2
2.0.0-alpha9
2.0.0-alpha8
2.0.0-alpha7
2.0.0-alpha6
```

See [more release information here](https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.android.tools.build.gradle/view).

Answer (score 0):

Got his today - I was using

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0-beta2'
```

and by letting the wizards fix it, I ended up with

```
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0
```

Answer (score 0):

This is common when you use development versions, the error will reoccur as soon as your version is far enough behind the current version, the solution is of course to upgrade to a more recent version.

If you need the latest version numbers, I've been keeping a **list of the most current versions** up-to-date on my answer to this similar question:

**[Android Studio 2.0 - Plugin is too old, please update to a more recent version, or set ANDROID_DAILY_OVERRIDE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35627431/984830)**