# Plugin is too old, please update to a more recent version,or set ANDROID_DAILY_OVERRIDE (Note:I use Android Studio 2.0 Preview 9 Version)

Tags: android, android-studio, runtime-error

### I worked on my project issueless last night but this morning suddenly I got this error:

```
Plugin is too old, please update to a more recent version, or set ANDROID_DAILY_OVERRIDE environment variable to "4a50f93953bc93b160920b1956a20e4942372a86"

Error:(1, 1) A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> Failed to apply plugin [id 'com.android.application']
   > Could not create plugin of type 'AppPlugin'.
```

I use Android Studio 2.0 Preview 9 Version

I checked to update and download new version tools from SDK Manager

I download gradle 2.11 and changed gradle distribution from file/Settings/gradle on Android Studio

All this solution can not solve my problem yet.

Any idea or solution about this error ?

### My build.gradle(Module) Partititon

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.myproject.myprojectname"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1'
}
```

### My build.gradle(Project) Partition

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0-alpha9'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Plugin is too old, please update to a more recent version, or set ANDROID\_DAILY\_OVERRIDE environment variable to](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29063968/plugin-is-too-old-please-update-to-a-more-recent-version-or-set-android-daily)

Comment: I tried answers from that question but not one of work for me.

Comment: Don't download your own gradle distribution.... That's what the gradle wrapper is for... Just change the gradle version in the gradle.properties for of your wrapper to update to a newer version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I deleted the Android Studio 2.0 Preview 9 and I loaded Android Studio 1.5.1 after that the problem solved. Thanks you guys helping to me..

Answer (score 1):

cahnge 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0-alpha9' to 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0-alpha6'

or try to update the ide (in the dev channel) and it will fix it self

Answer (score 0):

*Other answers here are correct but out of date, because this question does not get as much traffic.*

This error indicates you are using a development environment that is far enough out of date that it could cause weird side effects, the solution is of course to upgrade to a more recent version.

I maintain an answer with a **list of the most current versions** here:

**[Android Studio 2.0 - Plugin is too old, please update to a more recent version, or set ANDROID_DAILY_OVERRIDE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35627431/984830)**