# Android Studio 2.0 - this version of Android Studio is incompatible with the Gradle Plugin used. Try disabling Instant Run

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio-2.0

I updated the Android Studio version 2.0 preview 6 and was used it long normally.But When I created a new project today, it is displaying the error Plugin is too old, please update to a more recent version, or set ANDROID_DAILY_OVERRIDE environment variable to

I looked it up to find solution like in the link : 
[Android Studio 2.0 - Plugin is too old, please update to a more recent version, or set ANDROID_DAILY_OVERRIDE environment variable to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34572458/android-studio-2-0-plugin-is-too-old-please-update-to-a-more-recent-version)
 Changed my build.gradle (Project) classpath and gradle-wrapper.properties, But now the project builds properly but does not run, 
The error shown is "***This version of Android Studio is incompatible with the Gradle Plugin used. Try disabling Instant Run.***"
Couldnt find any solution for the same. Im an beginner, any help would be appreciated.

**My app/build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 'Google Inc.:Google APIs:23'
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.timercheck"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.+'
}
```

**My build.gradle (Project)**

```
    // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

    buildscript {
        repositories {
            jcenter()
        }
        dependencies {
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0-beta6'

            // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
            // in the individual module build.gradle files
        }
    }

    allprojects {
        repositories {
            jcenter()
        }
    }

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: Open the setting & check which gradle version you use ..
Note you need to use the latest one as android studio

Comment: http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/instant-run please check it

Comment: https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/ here all plugin available...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[image]

1. In settings, search `Instant Run` and clear `Enable instant run` to hot swap code.
2. Clean project

Comment: Working fine. Thanks