# How to update Gradle Plugin version?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I am trying to run a project and it shows me:

> Error running app: This version of Android Studio is incompatible with
>   the Gradle Plugin used. Try disabling Instant Run (or updating either
>   the IDE or the Gradle plugin to the latest version)

What should I do?

How can I update gradle?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Studio 2.0 - this version of Android Studio is incompatible with the Gradle Plugin used. Try disabling Instant Run](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36170487/android-studio-2-0-this-version-of-android-studio-is-incompatible-with-the-gra)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to update gradle in android studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17727645/how-to-update-gradle-in-android-studio)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The gradle plugin is declared inside the build.gradle file in your modules or in your root folder (top-level file).

Use:

```
 classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0'
```

Also this requires gradle 2.10 (don't confuse the gradle plugin with gradle).
The gradle version is defined in `gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties`.

Use:

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.10-all.zip
```

Comment: thimbs up for difference between gradle plugin and gradle version, clean and complete answer!

Comment: another thumbs up for pointing out the diff between gradle and android gradle plugin versions

Comment: For the new Gradle 3.3 update, usue the following: `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-3.3-all.zip`

Comment: after doing this i am not able to run app in release mode any help please?

Answer (score 3):

For automatic update, you may set the version in `Android Studio > File > Project Structure > Project > Android Plugin Version`

[image]

Please note that you might also need to update `Gradle Version`. For gradle and gradle plugin compatibility, you may refer to the [docs](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin.html).

Sync gradle afterwards. This will automatically set the distribution URL as well.