# Gradle sync failed: The android gradle plugin version 2.3.0-beta1 is too old, please update to the latest version

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, wrapper, beta

Here i am getting strange issue because my android studio version &  Gradle wrapper are updated with new version & still getting below issue:

Gradle sync failed: The android Gradle plugin version 2.3.0-beta1 is too old, please update to the latest version.

To override this check from the command line please set the ANDROID_DAILY_OVERRIDE environment variable to "e7cc61d747b236b3626248d02049407dfb0f8ae3".

**Android studio : 2.3 Beta 3**

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.0-beta1'
```

**gradle-wrapper.properties**

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-3.3-all.zip
```

Please drop your comments if anyone found this.

Comment: are you building your project with `wrapper`?

Comment: did you checked this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34572458/android-studio-2-0-plugin-is-too-old-please-update-to-a-more-recent-version

Comment: This is my config:  distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.14.1-all.zip . classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'

Comment: Yes, @wrkwrk if I use old one then it will work, but while I am updating it with the latest version 2.3.0-beta1  it does not work and showing pop-up to update.

Comment: what is your android studio version ?

Comment: 2.3 Beta 3 @VivekMishra

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to update classpath 
`classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.0-beta3` instead of beta1

Answer (score 3):

**For stable release:** You are using the incompatible version between `distributionUrl` and `classpath`.
Try this the latest gradle distribution for android studio:
Android plugin for Gradle, revision 2.3.1

```
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.1'
    distributionUrl = https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-3.5-all.zip
```

**For beta release**
[Instead get preview builds at](https://developer.android.com/studio/preview/index.html)

**For stable release**
[Get the stable release at](https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

Check **gradle.properties** file. In my case i had a configured proxy.