# update to buildToolsVersion 25 results ClassNotFoundException

Tags: android, gradle, build-tools

I had such setup and all was fine.
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'

After increase to:
b uildToolsVersion '25.0.0'
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.0'
I got ClassNotFoundException for one of my providers.
I have tried with 24.0.3 - same issue.

P.S. i can't make compileSdkVersion lower, because app is in market

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing that helped me to use latest libraries:

```
public class AppClass extends Application {
//this will initialize multidex in your own Application class
  @Override
  protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
      super.attachBaseContext(base);
      MultiDex.install(this);
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try with this lines

compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion '25.0.0'

Comment: ok , you can check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34572458/android-studio-2-0-plugin-is-too-old-please-update-to-a-more-recent-version?answertab=active#tab-top

Comment: i have already, gradle 2.3.0 needs gradle-wrapper 3.3 that needs buildToolsVersion 25.0.0 - and i got crash