# Unable to run android project due to old plug-in error after recent update

Tags: android, android-studio

Currently, I'm having trouble trying to solve the old plug-in error in android studio. I got the following error, but have no clue how to solve 
the problem. There were similar problems in stackoverflow, but none of the solution helped. Are there anyone here who might know the solution ?
Some step by step explanation will be great if available! I would love to here from you!

> Error:(1, 0) Plugin is too old, please update to a more recent
>   version, or set ANDROID_DAILY_OVERRIDE environment variable to
>   "fabe6db51edae26ca766bdae73"

Comment: the easiest way - create template project, copy/paste  gradle content to your files. Seems that you use old android plugin there, use "apply plugin: 'com.android.application' "

Comment: Is the apply plugin in gradle file ? And what exactly should I apply ?

Comment: gradle is a build system, it doesn't know a thing about your project, until you apply a plugin (e.g. java, .net, android...). in your build.gradle file there are apply lines (e.g. apply plugin: 'com.android.application') , so you need to be sure that you use new plugin.

Comment: Already answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29063968/plugin-is-too-old-please-update-to-a-more-recent-version-or-set-android-daily

Comment: Thank you all! problem solved!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your project's build.gradle file change your buildscript block in the dependencies part

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:something'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
```

for this

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0-alpha3'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
```

ad sync.