# How can I update my plugin in android studio?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I am building a golf score card app with android studio and last night before I shut down my laptop it was building fine, however, this morning when I run Android studio I got the error "Plugin is too old, please update to a more recent version, or set ANDROID_DAILY_OVERRIDE environment variable to "aed79d567e57792ed352e708d2b7ca891ff897c6"" and my app structure has also altered and there is no longer a manifest folder.....[image of app structure``](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Ge6k.png)

Below is my gradle file:

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.biko.golfstroke"
        minSdkVersion 8
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
}
```

Please help if you can this is so frustrating!

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29063968/plugin-is-too-old-please-update-to-a-more-recent-version-or-set-android-daily

Comment: I don't want to distract you, but as I noticed you are using API 23 to compile and target, I want to make sure you are using the newest technique in granting permissions: http://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Comment: Thanks Astrount, I'm just reading the documentation on the newest technique in requesting and granting permissions from the link you shared...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PLZ update your gradle plugin version in the rooter gradle file as following:

> classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0-alpha6'

check the newest version of android gradle plugin in [here](https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.android.tools.build.gradle/view)

I think the android studio should fix this version problem by himself, it`s a bad experience for changing it manually.

Comment: Just in few days , android released the lastest alpha7 version, so here is another solution: classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:+', this can let the gradle always update the newest version...

Answer (score 0):

I changed my class path to: `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0-alpha6'`

and then followed this post:[change distribution url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34814368/gradle-version-2-10-is-required-error)

and it was solved....
Thanks for all the help!