# Plugin is too old, please update to a more recent version, or set ANDROID_DAILY_OVERRIDE environment variable

Tags: android, build.gradle

Showing this error on running my project, I tried all the solution available but it's not working. The only thing left is to set the `ANDROID_DAILY_OVERRIDE` environment variable, but I am struggling to do so.

How I can set `ANDROID_DAILY_OVERRIDE` environment variable on a mac?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Plugin is too old, please update to a more recent version, or set ANDROID\_DAILY\_OVERRIDE environment variable to](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29063968/plugin-is-too-old-please-update-to-a-more-recent-version-or-set-android-daily)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change your build.gradle file to

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0-alpha6'
```

Also navigate to to yourProjectPath/Gradle/wrapper
and open the gradle-wrapper.properties

Change distributionURL with

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.10-all.zip
```

I hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for the reply but it doesn't, solve. after that I get this error Error:(62, 0) Gradle DSL method not found: 'comiple()'
Possible causes:<ul><li>The project 'everybill-codebase' may be using a version of Gradle that does not contain the method.
<a href="open.wrapper.file">Open Gradle wrapper file</a></li><li>The build file may be missing a Gradle plugin.
<a href="apply.gradle.plugin">Apply Gradle plugin</a></li>

Comment: Sorry to hear that, that did the work for me. Did you force a gradle sync after the changes ?

Comment: yes , do you know how to  set ANDROID_DAILY_OVERRIDE environment variable in mac

Comment: above solution worked after I deleted app indexing dependency in build.gradle . the issue was caused by that as it was not having some method Gradle DSL method not found: 'comiple()'

Answer (score 4):

Since you asked how to set the environment variable on OS X here it goes:

`launchctl setenv ANDROID_DAILY_OVERRIDE <your-value-on-error-message>`

Restart Android Studio and the project will build again.

Kudos to UPDATE 2 here: https://emmanuelbernard.com/blog/2012/05/09/setting-global-variables-intellij/

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am still facing the issue. Here is the link of my new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35127166/gradle-dsl-method-not-found-comiple-after-putting-gcm-dependency

Comment: The problem you're having is not related at all with this issue, I answered there. Also please kindly consider to mark this answer as the correct one in order to help others.

Answer (score 0):

change classpath in gradle from

classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0-beta6'

to:

classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'

then restart its work for me for android studio 2.0 Beta 6