# Gradle DSL method not found: 'comiple()' after putting gcm dependency

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, build.gradle

I am facing this issue once I put the dependency of GCM.

Error:(50, 0) Gradle DSL method not found: 'comiple()'
Possible causes:The project 'everybill-codebase' may be using a version of Gradle that does not contain the method.
Open Gradle wrapper fileThe build file may be missing a Gradle plugin.
Apply Gradle plugin

This is the build.gradle file of line no 50,

```
comiple 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.4.0'
```

I am using these services also from play-service

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:8.4.0'
```

this is the build.gradle file in project

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0-alpha6'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:2.0.0-alpha6'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

It would be great to know any solution related with this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `comiple()` or `compile()` ? Which version of gradle are you using ?

Comment: There is a typo in comiple instead of compile

Comment: Thanks. reading your comment  I realised how much time I wasted due to a minor mistake. BTW thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Eventually someone is going to close this question, but as the other guys pointed out it's just a typo, use `compile()` instead of `comiple()`.