# Error:(1, 0) Plugin is too old and ANDROID_DAILY_OVERRIDE value is also outdated, please use new value :"11f0c8f6a19f6b805f4d0f4ecbec99d777fb7c60"

Tags: android

Plugin is too old and ANDROID_DAILY_OVERRIDE value is also outdated, please use new value "" can someone help to resolve this ? 
    its happening after I added few compile  dependencies I have tried few solutions but it isn't working  I have uploaded both the codes, someone help here I am putting codes

```
    Build.gradle



        // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

        buildscript {
            repositories {
                jcenter()
            }
            dependencies {
                classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0-alpha1'
                classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.4'
                classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:1.5.0-beta2'


                // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
                // in the individual module build.gradle files
            }
        }

        allprojects {
            repositories {
                jcenter()
            }
        }



    App.gradle








    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
    apply plugin: 'android-apt'
    def AAVersion = '3.3.1'

    buildscript {
        repositories {
            maven { url "http://dl.bintray.com/populov/maven" }
            mavenCentral()

        }
        dependencies {
            // replace with the current version of the android-apt plugin
            classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.4'
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0-alpha1'




        }
    }

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        mavenLocal()

    }
    dependencies {
        apt "org.androidannotations:androidannotations:$AAVersion"
        compile "org.androidannotations:androidannotations-api:$AAVersion"
        compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp-android-support:2.5.0'
        compile 'com.squareup.okio:okio:1.6.0'
    }

    apt {
        arguments {
            androidManifestFile variant.outputs[0].processResources.manifestFile
            // if you have multiple outputs (when using splits), you may want to have other index than 0

            // You can set optional annotation processing options here, like these commented options:
            // logLevel 'INFO'
            // logFile '/var/log/aa.log'
        }
    }

    android {
        compileSdkVersion 22
        buildToolsVersion '22.0.1'

        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.vedicrishiastro.kundli"
            minSdkVersion 15
            targetSdkVersion 22
            versionCode 5
            versionName "Beta 1.3"
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }
    }

    /*apt {
        arguments {
            //androidManifestFile variant.outputs[0].processResources.manifestFile
            // if you have multiple outputs (when using splits), you may want to have other index than 0

            // If you're using flavors you should use the following line instead of hard-coded packageName
             resourcePackageName android.defaultConfig.applicationId

            // You can set optional annotation processing options here, like these commented options:
            // logLevel 'INFO'
            // logFile '/var/log/aa.log'
        }
    }*/

    dependencies {
        compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        compile 'com.clevertap.android:clevertap-android-sdk'
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services'
        compile 'com.android.support:support-v4'

        compile project(':multilevelexpindlistview')
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
        compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:22.2.0'
        compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.0'
        apt "org.androidannotations:androidannotations:$AAVersion"
        compile "org.androidannotations:androidannotations-api:$AAVersion"
        compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:21.0.+'
        compile 'com.github.traex.rippleeffect:library:1.3'
        compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:21.0.+'
        compile 'com.rengwuxian.materialedittext:library:2.1.4'
        compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'
        compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.4.0'
        compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:1.3.0'
        compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
        compile project(':library')
        compile 'com.github.medyo:fancybuttons:1.5@aar'
        compile 'com.jpardogo.materialtabstrip:library:1.1.0'
        compile 'com.melnykov:floatingactionbutton:1.3.0'
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:8.3.0'
        compile 'uk.co.chrisjenx:calligraphy:2.1.0'


    }
    android {
        lintOptions {
            abortOnError false
            checkReleaseBuilds false
        }
    }


    apply plugin: 'android-apt'
    apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: at first set `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.8.0'` instead of yours

Comment: @IntelliJ Amiya i tried but it isn't working

Comment: `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0-beta2'`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29063968/plugin-is-too-old-please-update-to-a-more-recent-version-or-set-android-daily?rq=1

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya now i am getting  Error:Could not find com.clevertap.android:clevertap-android-sdk:.
Required by:
    kundli:app:unspecified

Comment: call this `compile 'com.clevertap.android:clevertap-android-sdk:2.0.5'`

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya thank you so much it worked!! thanks alot amiya i was facing this problem from yesterday but at last you helped thanks, keep rocking!

Comment: Move ahead .Glad to help.

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya i did but it says i need to have 15 reputations to get diaplayed my votes

Comment: You can accept this answer by clicking `"Right Sign"`

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya i did!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Call**

```
compile 'com.clevertap.android:clevertap-android-sdk:2.0.5'
```

And **Upgrade** this

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0-beta2'
```