# "Error:Plugin is too old" What is wrong with this gradle?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

It throws the following errors.

> Error:Plugin is too old, please update to a more recent version, or
>   set ANDROID_DAILY_OVERRIDE environment variable to
>   "ccbf255801ffbc86319e3fd14bdc0682272bf5c9"
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> Where:
>     Build file 'E:\srk\android\app\build.gradle' line: 1
>
> What went wrong:
>       A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'. Failed to apply plugin [id 'com.android.application'] Could not create plugin of type
>   'AppPlugin'.
>
> Try:
>       Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or   --debug option to get more log output.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

    android {
        compileSdkVersion 23
        buildToolsVersion "24.0.1"

        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.vineyard.crash"
            minSdkVersion 10
            targetSdkVersion 23

            ndk {
                moduleName "player_shared"
            }
        }

        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
            }
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
        compile files('libs/dagger-1.2.2.jar')
        compile files('libs/javax.inject-1.jar')
        compile files('libs/nineoldandroids-2.4.0.jar')
        compile files('libs/PTAdVungle.jar')
        compile files('libs/support-v4-19.0.1.jar')
    }
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/29063968/2435238

Answer (score 1):

try this change in your project build.gradle and sync gradle again

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.3'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem, my problem was solved by adding below line in top level gradle

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.2'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue, and i solved it just changing my build.gradle

From this:

`classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.2"`

To this:

```
classpath('com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.2') {
    force = true
}
```

I hope it's help's you